# KineticJs : puzzle not displaying whole image?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, puzzle

currently i have a problem displaying my whole image with my puzzle and with the "click" rotation it had a bug which when i click one piece other piece also rotates why? Can anyone help me see my fiddle and help me with it? thanks so much

```
    fillPatternImage:imageObj,
                    x:-pieceWidth*i,
                    y:-pieceHeight*j,
                    stroke: "#000000",
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    lineCap: "round",
                    rotation : Math.PI * 0.5 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4),
                    draggable: true,
                    offset: [pieceWidth/2,pieceHeight/2],
                x: pieceWidth*i+pieceWidth/2 + (Math.random()*2)*((stage.getWidth()+pieceWidth)/20),
                y: pieceHeight*j+pieceHeight/2 + (Math.random()*2)*((stage.getHeight()+pieceHeight)/20),
            });
            piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("mousedown", function(){
                this.moveToTop();
                });
            piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("click", function(){
                this.moveToTop();
                this.rotateDeg(90)
                });
```

My JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/

Thanks

Comment: Can't help you with your first question, but the rotation problem is because you're not drawing after you rotate. Add `stage.draw();` after `this.rotateDeg(90)`

Comment: sorry , but it still had a bug where when i click and drag and it doesnt rotates but only rotates after i release it, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
piecesArray[i][j].shape.on("click", function(){
    this.moveToTop();
    this.rotateDeg(90)
    layer.draw();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/2/

Comment: sorry , but it still had a bug where when i click and drag and it doesnt rotates but only rotates after i release it, why? and sorry for the trouble, do you have any idea why my picture cant come out? thanks :)

Comment: Why it should rotate? I don't see code for this. You are using very old version of KineticJS. I think it is better to use last one. It will not trigger `click` event after dragging. So you can change event to `dragstart`.

Comment: Explain second question. "Come out" - of what? What do you mean here?

Comment: Sorry, i cant use the latest version of the kineticJS as it will show me error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/, so i decided to use the older version which would not actually give me any error. yea thanks :) dragstart can solve my bug :)

Comment: About the second question, actually i have been trying out 2 test of my coding, 1 which i context.moveto(offsetX,offsetY) which allow me to show my whole picture after cut into pieces, but once i change to context.moveto(0,0) it doesnt shows anymore why? 2 version fiddle i include here to let you take a look :) 1st with the whole picture but after the rotation code i added in i cant see some of my pieces which i dont know why: http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/29/ , the second one is this which doesnt show my whole picture :  http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/3/